# count(*)+group by+having

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, having

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `un_tr` (
  `ut_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_p_c` double NOT NULL,
  `d_c` double NOT NULL,
  `tr_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ev_t` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ut_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `un_tr` (`ut_id`, `date`, 
`s_p_c`, `d_c`, `tr_id`, `ev_type`) VALUES
(1, '2018-06-01', 20.33333, 21.33333, 1, 'accident', NULL),
(2, '2018-07-02', 21.33333, 23.33333, 1, 'accident', NULL),
(3, '2018-06-03', 21.33333, 24.33333, 1, 'accident', NULL),
(4, '2018-06-04', 25.33333, 26.33333, 1, 'travel', NULL),
(5, '2018-06-04', 21.33333, 26.33333, 2, 'travel', NULL),
(6, '2018-06-04', 21.33333, 26.33333, 2, 'accident', NULL),
(7, '2018-06-04', 21.33333, 26.33333, 2, 'travel', NULL),
(8, '2018-06-04', 21.33333, 26.33333, 3, 'travel', NULL),
(9, '2018-08-04', 19.33333, 26.33333, 4, 'travel', NULL);
```

and  I need get just one record count(ut.tr_id)

```
select  count(distinct ut.tr_id) as count_tr from un_tr ut group  by ut.tr_id having count(ut.ut_id)>1
```

but I got the result :

```
count_tr
1
1
```

I would like to get the result:

```
count_tr
2
```

Would you like give me advice, how do i may do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you not just wrap that query in a select count(*) from (subquery)

Comment: which SQL engine ?

Answer (score 2):

You query

```
select  count(distinct ut.tr_id) as count_tr 
from un_tr ut 
group  by ut.tr_id 
having count(ut.ut_id)>1
```

can be simplified to

```
select  ut.tr_id
from un_tr ut 
group  by ut.tr_id 
having count(ut.ut_id)>1
```

since there is no point in doing a `count(distinct ut.tr_id)`: the `group by ut.tr_id` has as a consequence that this count is *always* 1 per `ut.tr_id`.

You can now count the number of distinct `tr_id` occurrences just by:

```
select count(*)
from
(
   select  ut.tr_id
   from un_tr ut 
   group  by ut.tr_id 
   having count(ut.ut_id)>1

) as t
```

Comment: it's answer is fine , thanks but i would like in same query add additional filter like:      select count(*)
from 
(
   select  ut.tr_id
   from un_tr ut 
   group  by ut.tr_id 
   having count(ut.ut_id)>1

) as t

Comment: it answers is fine, thanks but I would like the same query to add an additional filter like                                                                                                    select count(*)
from 
(
   select  ut.tr_id
   from un_tr ut 
   group  by ut.tr_id 
   having count(ut.ut_id)>1

) as t  .What do you give advice?

Comment: @OlegShevtsov I have no picture of your actual data set and I also don't know about the purpose of the filter, so it is hard for me to give any useful advice.

Comment: Maybe it gives you some picture: select count(*)
from un_tr ut where date between  '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-01' 
(
   select  ut.tr_id
   from un_tr ut 
   group  by ut.tr_id 
   having count(ut.ut_id)>1

) as t This query is wrong, but here is filer.

Comment: @OlegShevtsov Try this to see if it works: `select count(*) from   ( select ut.tr_id from un_tr ut where date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-01' group by ut.tr_id having count(ut.ut_id)>1 ) as t`

Comment: Yes, it works, but i think i don't show all task, sorry. I would like get query  like select  count(*) as count_tr, 
count(CASE WHEN ut.ev_t = 'accident' THEN 1 END) AS u_t_a
 from 
(select distinct traveller_id as dtr_id 
from universe_traffic ut 
where date between '2018-06-01' and '2018-06-31'
group  by ut.traveller_id 
having count(ut.ut_id)>1) a and it don't work

Comment: @OlegShevtsov Comments are not the right place trying to answer questions. I tried to answer to the question posted. If you have a different question then try writing a separate post where you explain your actual requirement.

Comment: Maybe you look out here and say any idea, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718866/2-countgroup-byhavingjoin

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query:

```
select count(*) as count_tr from (
   select distinct tr_id as dtr_id, count(ut_id)
   from un_tr 
   group by dtr_id
   having count(ut_id) > 1
  ) a;
```

Result:

```
+----------+
| count_tr |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
```

Comment: it answers is fine, thanks but I would like the same query to add an additional filter like                                                                                                    select count(*)
from 
(
   select  ut.tr_id
   from un_tr ut 
   group  by ut.tr_id 
   having count(ut.ut_id)>1

) as t .What do you give advice?

Comment: You could add a `WHERE` clause in the inner query. For example, this query will only limit the `tr_id` to `2`, and give count of `1`. `select count(*) from ( select ut.tr_id from un_tr ut where d_c > 26.0  group by ut.tr_id having count(ut.ut_id) > 1 ) as t;`